# Run some code in the main thread from a worker thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I have to signal the Main thread to run some code from one of the worker thread.

That code must run in the main thread because of some COM issue( running it on the thread just fail).

I was starting to implement it with messages and event (i need to wait the code to be executed before going foward) when i remebered there was some very simple and straight way to do it in Java And SWT)

```
  display.syncExec (new Runnable () {
  public void run () {
     if (!myWindow.isDisposed())
        myWindow.redraw ();
  }
```

Anything similar for MFC and windows in general?

Comment: Lishi, Don't forget to manage the message pump on your thread!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PostThreadMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WinAPI function to send `WM_USER` message to main thread. Then you can handle `WM_USER` in main thread and do some necessary actions.

Comment: Don't use PostThreadMessage to a thread that also displays a user interface.  Any modal loop will cause such a message to fall in the bit bucket.  Such as used when resizing a window, displaying a message box, showing a dialog.  Use PostMessage().